# Replacing only specific column values in an array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, replace, nan

I have an array that has about 70,000 rows that look like the following:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 723 1 22

      1 2 3 4 5 7 0 NaN 2 10 

      etc..                 ]
```

I would like to replace all NaN values in my array with the preceding value in the same column as the NaN value so that I would have something like this:

```
B = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 723 1 22

      1 2 3 4 5 7 0 723 2 10 

      etc..                 ]
```

Since the array has about 70,000 rows, I am guessing some sort of loop would be the best way to achieve this. Using the following:

```
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
        I = A(1,ii);
        for jj = 2:size(A,1)
            if isnan(A(jj,ii))
                A(jj,ii) = I;
            else
                I  = A(jj,ii);
            end
        end
        end
```

I have been able to make a loop that replaces the whole row with the preceding row, but I am unsure how to modify it to target only NaN values. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are now `NaN`'s in the first row, you can just replace the values directly:

```
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
    for jj = 2:size(A,1)
        if isnan(A(jj,ii))
            A(jj,ii) = A(jj-1,ii);
        end
    end
end
```

Which avoids creating a second matrix `B`.

I think you're right, an you do need to use `for`-loops since your matrix is so large, but here is a non-`for` loop version anyway:

```
while(any(isnan(A(:))))
    A(find(isnan(A)))=A(find(isnan(A))-1)
end
```

Comment: Why the `while` loop? The `find` line does the job by itself, doesn't it?

Comment: @LuisMendo if there are two or more `NaN`'s on top of each other you need to repeat the process, because the bottom `NaN` will be replaced by the `NaN` above it.

Comment: Got it. The OP doesn't say what to do if there are several NaN's together on top of each other, but this is a good generalization. +1 already

Comment: Now I see the OP's last pseudocode part does "say" that :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo yeah it's not explicitly stated, but neither is what happens if there is a `NaN` in the top row!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The other suggested method is a better fit in this particular case but that you nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the `I = A(1, ii);` or the `else` branch is needed. If a `NaN` is found, just replace it with the value from the previous row:

```
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
    for jj = 2:size(A,1)
        if (isnan(A(jj,ii)))
            A(jj,ii) = A(jj-1, ii); %jj-1 is the previous row
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You're welcome, @ficus. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.